# Using HAC in ARIMA model

Tags: arima, hac

I have a model in EViews (made by a third party) and it looks like this

```
dlnY c dlnX1 dlnX2 ar(1)
```

Additionally for the covariance method "HAC (Newely-West)" is used.

HAC is used as there is some heteroscedasticity, and it removes it nicely. But some autocorrelation remains which should be taken care of with ar(1) (however it is not; in fact, testing of the model showed that ar(1) ar(2) and ar(3) are all significant).

Shouldn't HAC (in theory) take care of autocorrelation? How is it justifiable to use both AR and HAC at the same time?
Also, I am skeptical about "post-hoc" optimization. What is the general opinion about that?

Comment: You are missing the point. Your residuals are correlated, but the HAC estimator of the variance-covariance matrix ensures that the standard errors of the coefficient estimates in your mean equation are not under-stated despite the correlation in the residuals.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. How about the part of the question about "post-hoc" optimization of coefficients?

Comment: See [these threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=diebold+hac) for a discussion of HAC standard errors vs. explicitly modelling the patterns in the error term.